# PHP script doesn't stop after error

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using CodeIgniter framework and
After testing in XAMPP, a normal error like "Missing argument" the php script stops and it shows me the PHP Warning page, however in the hosting server(e.g. GoDaddy) the php script takes a while to stop and it shows me the 500 error page, 
consequently the server has a new Entry Process.

Any idea?
Thanks!

```
   public function getAQByLocation($city) {
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $ch = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://api.waqi.info/feed/$city/?
        token=" . $this->AQ_API_KEY);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

        $result = curl_exec($ch);

        if (curl_errno($ch)) {
            echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
        }
        curl_close ($ch);

        echo $result;
    }
```

This is the code, to simulate that error i just omitted the parameter $city, e.g. xxx.com/Home/getAQByLocation

Comment: Show some code, also get the error logs

Comment: @Thamaraiselvam Updated, however i can't find the log of that error, best regards.

Comment: check your index.php ENVIRONMENT setting: "Setting the environment also influences things like logging and error reporting."

Comment: @Vickel i manage to set into index.php the line
    define('ENVIRONMENT', 'development');
however it continues to give me that error.

Comment: I don't really understand what you want to achieve. 500 is server error, most likely because of curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://api.waqi.info/feed/$city/?" (if $city='' you have 2 backslashes before the question mark!). Ask you service provider, where you find the error log files

Comment: @Vickel the thing is that it doesn't matter what function i'm trying to access, even the 404 error gives me the 500 error in side of codeigniter project. Thank you for you answer

Comment: the solution was to set the value $config['log_threshold'] = 1; in the config.php. Thank you every one!

Comment: @JuanRamos, post your answer as the correct one so others may benefit from it in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the solution was to set the value

$config['log_threshold'] = 1;

in the config.php. Thank you every one!